# Can you use nAGQ = 0 with the Poisson distribution?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, convergence, glmm

I am working with a GLM with lots of random variables and Poisson distribution. I get the error 'boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular' and so looked up ways around this. I found someone recommended `nAGQ = 0` for binomial distribution. Can I use this for the Poisson distribution? How does it actually work? (Once I add this to my model it works really well.)

```
glmer(Total ~ Treatment + (1|Number) + (1|Site), data, family=poisson, nAGQ=0)
```